# How to make fail2ban use pyinotify on fresh ubuntu 20.04 install?

Tags: ubuntu, fail2ban, inotify

I just created a new Ubuntu 20.04 server. I installed Fail2Ban for ssh protection. I noticed in /var/log/fail2ban.log that the sshd jail starts with "poller" as the backend. I haven't changed the configuration files; `backend = auto` is in effect, and the first preference should be pyinotify.

Well, inotify wasn't installed on the system, so I did an `apt-get install inotify-tools inotify-hookable python-pyinotify`, then I did a `service fail2ban restart`. The log still shows it's using the poller backend.

So my question here is: how do I make Fail2Ban use pyinotify on a clean Ubuntu 20.04 system?

Answer (score 2):

No idea which python fail2ban package uses on Ubuntu per default, but I guess it is python3 (you could try to check it with `fail2ban-python --version`).

If so, just install `python3-pyinotify` (package `python-pyinotify` is for python2).